# Material list items look different when rendered through template

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material list where I want to render items based on a template provided from the outside. However, this seems to affect how the `mat-list-item` component renders content, in particular for `matLine` children.

Explicitly defining an items rendering as follows works as expected:

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    <h4 matLine [title]="item.name">{{item.name}}</h4>
    <p matLine class="item-id">{{item.id}}</p>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

However, when using a template (provided as `@ContentChild`) the rendered list ends up looking different:

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: item}"></ng-template>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Template passed in:

```
<ng-template let-item>
  <h4 matLine [title]="item.name">{{item.name}}</h4>
  <p matLine class="item-id">{{item.id}}</p>
</ng-template>
```

One example difference is that the former example ends up wrapping `matLine`s into a `div.mat-list-text` element, while the latter doesn't.

Why do those two examples behave differently, and how can I align them?

#### Update

It looks like the problem is that [`mat-list-item`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/list/list-item.html#L10) transcludes provided children selectively using `<ng-content select="...">`.
Judging from [a bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842), this doesn't seem to work for content children provided through templates at the moment.