# Selectively render items from ng-template, similar to ng-content's select attribute

Tags: angular, angular2-template

With transclusion in Angular with `ng-content`, items can be filtered using the `select` attribute. For example, this will only render image elements of the ones passed as content children:

```xml
<ng-content select="img"></ng-content>
```

Now, there's the `ngTemplateOutlet` directive for rendering templates, for example:

```xml
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="myTemplate"></ng-container>

<ng-template #myTemplate>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <img src="foo.jpg">
</ng-template>
```

My question is how to filter contents from `myTemplate` to be rendered, for example if I would like to just get all `img` elements. Apparently, there is no such thing as a `select` property on the `ngTemplateOutlet` directive.

Comment: Creating a component with an `<ng-content select="img">` and passing the stamped content of the template to it might work. If you use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`, you can pass transcluded content as far as I remember. I haven't tried that myself yet though.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That doesn't seem to work because [transclusion doesn't work with NgTemplateOutlet (bug)](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14842). That's is actually my motivation for this question, as I'm trying to find a workaround to that problem ([my related other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885519/material-list-items-look-different-when-rendered-through-template)).

Comment: Sad to hear :-/

Comment: Thank you @GünterZöchbauer: your suggestion of passing a template into a child component's `ng-content` worked for my particular situation.